# React: using a class in Minimal HTML Template

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use the [Minimal HTML Template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/master/static/html/single-file-example.html) from the ["Try React" page](https://reactjs.org/docs/try-react.html).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );

    </script>
    <!--
      Note: this page is a great way to try React but it's not suitable for production.
      It slowly compiles JSX with Babel in the browser and uses a large development build of React.

      To set up a production-ready React build environment, follow these instructions:
      * https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-new-app.html
      * https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-an-existing-app.html

      You can also use React without JSX, in which case you can remove Babel:
      * https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html
      * https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Hmmm.... I want to add a class file to this dish. For example, the file **App.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You should try react-create-app for such starter kit. It will be much easier for you I think.

Comment: @JulienTASSIN I did try.... that's where I took the App.js from, and it works fine, but requires installing dependencies. Now I am trying something different, which is why I posted this question.

Comment: Yes but create-app is bundled with a minimal webpack / babel / ... that will  allow you to import the class

Comment: I don't know too much about JS syntax. If `import` indeed requires installing dependencies, then I am fine with including the class file by a `<script>` element in the html `<head>`. Otherwise, I am fine with directly placing the class code in the main html file. I tried it but it was not rendered... I may be missing something. Any idea how to do that? I am trying to use classes without installing any dependencies, even if it means I will have to place all the code in one html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code would do, what you want to **try out** provided the `app.js`, `app.css` and the `logo.svg` are in the same folder as your `html`.
**THIS SHOULD NOT TO BE USED IN PRACTICE**. Because [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) is actually transpiling the [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) to JavaScript **on the browser**.
In the starter app, the transpilation is done at the build time and the browser simply needs to execute the script.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./App.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <App></App>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );

    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

and the modified `app.js`

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
      let logo = "./logo.svg";
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed!